# Doctors in the days of Moses

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, miracle

Where there doctors in the days of Moses following and treating sick people?
The Torah tell us that Hashem did heal people.But where there some doctors among them ?

Comment: This is not really a single question, but a multitude of questions centered around the Jewish conception of the role of the doctor. I suggest you either narrow your focus or split this into separate questions.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I agree and was think about that all along ,But I did think It would work as a complex question.But now there is an edit

Comment: The most common Hebrew word for doctor is רופא. With this in mind, the 1st occurrence of that word (similar) in the Torah is in Breishit 50:2. However, it doesn't appear to be a "healing" doctor as we know it, today. I can't say. But, this inspires me to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this book:

Fred Rosner, Medicine in the Bible and the Talmud: Selection from Classical Jewish Sources. Augmented
Edition, LJLE 5 (Hoboken NJ: Ktav Publishing House Inc./Yeshiva University Press, 1995).

Also:

http://etheses.dur.ac.uk/3568/1/THESIS_MariaChrysovergi.pdf?DDD32+

Comment: If you can summarize what that book says re whether there were doctors in Moshe Rabenu's time it could make this a great answer. Otherwise it should probably be a comment.

Answer (score 1):

In parshas Mishpatim chapter 21 verse 19 we find the term ורפא ירפא, someone who causes someone else damage must pay for his treatment to be healed.

This is a clear reference to human healing.

In fact the Talmud in Bava Kamma 85a uses this to prove that a doctor has permission to heal. Torah Temimah there explains that these words teach us that we should not think we are going against the will of God by healing someone He made sick.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. There is, perhaps, an inference that because the Torah mentions the term רפא that doctors did exist. But that's not directly apparent from this verse. All it says is that a doctor is allowed to heal the person.

Comment: You mean the Torah meant that when doctors will be invented they are given the right to heal? Does that make sense? By discussing doctors in the Torah we can assume they existed then.

Answer (score 0):

Moses, himself, was a doctor! See [B'midbar 21:9](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39995&st=&pgnum=159) and the verses preceding it. Fiery snakes bit much of the nation, and many were dying. Moses fashions a copper snake, and when people looked at it, they lived.

Granted, that Moses followed G-d's advice. The point is, that one can view this as being no different than a current doctor asking another doctor for advice on how to heal people. Even with the Talmud's interpretation of how this worked (I think it's in Talmud Megillah), the point is that in this incident, Moses still healed people. At least for this incident, it makes him a doctor.

Comment: But it was a miracle

Comment: @Aigle Miracles are how we perceive them. Was the Salk vaccine no less of a miracle, or would we disregard that only because Jonas Salk worked hard and found something important that just happened to work correctly and prevented the disease?

Comment: Medicin does not work as well as a Miracle,just a fact

Comment: @Aigle I'm neither agreeing nor disagreeing. It's just how we define what is a miracle. My answer may not fit the standard medical definition of "doctors" who use their medical knowledge. IMO, every doctor is merely a "messenger" to perform G-d's miracles. It still makes them a doctor.